# Hover over image and display above like EBAY and AMAZON

Tags: views, javascript, theming

I've tried searching but i cant figure out how to achieve this effect.

Basically i have a VIEW of a content type PICTURE. In the view a main Image is displayed and 3 other images displayed below it, i want to have an effect when a user hovers over one of the 3 images below then the main image shows that image, it doesnt matter if the image stays there or goes back to its original once users mouse goes off the image, but just having it change is what im struggling with. I see this effect done on Amazon as a good example.

Anyone have any ideas? Or even maybe a name for this sort of JQuery effect so i can search for it and try to implement it in to my Views TPL file or something?

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Are you asking about tpl part or html+js part? Because yea you can do it, but we can't write a whole functionality for you. We can guide you about finding name for tpl all right, for example... but not a whole functionality at once, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi You can use combination of [Views Slideshow](https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) & [Views Slideshow JCarousel](https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_jcarousel) to make such effect.

See this video also:

http://buildamodule.com/video/advanced-site-building-in-drupal-7-building-a-slideshow-using-views-slideshow-how-to-create-a-pager-of-thumbnail-images-in-views-slideshow

Comment: thank you very much, exactly what i was looking for :) much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If there is animation, there is likely some JavaScript involved, but you can do hover effects with CSS alone.

Just work with the markup you get from views and do something like this:

```
<div class="hover-here">
  <img src='#' />
  <div class="to-display"><p>Some Text to show</p></div>
</div>
```

Example CSS

```
.to-display { display: none; }
.hover-here:hover .to-display { display: block; }
```

Obviously you would want to use the markup supplied from views instead of the code above, but this should work.